# How to trace a C program by hiding header files in visual C++?

Tags: c++

I am using visual studio for last few months. When I trace a C program
it will show line by line execution including the lines in the header files. It will take lot of time to trace it.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint where you want to start debugging at.

Comment: of course i already did it.but i dont want to go to the header files while tracing it.

Comment: @ArunKumarmn: That already shouldn't happen. How are you doing this "tracing"? If you explain what you're doing then we might be able to suggest changes to your workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic method of all debugging:

1)Know what your program is supposed to do.

2)Detect when it doesn't. Print some values with printf()

3)Fix it.

This [link](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)Debugging.html) might be useful.

Comment: How does this relate to stepping through lines of code in Visual Studio? As the question specifies Visual Studio, it would make much more sense to talk about breakpoints in that IDE.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @NathanOliver's comment about breakpoints, make sure you're also using "Step Over" (F10) instead of "Step Into" (F11) (here's [more info on that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)).

If you truly want to change what functions are stepped into, you can do that on a per-function basis by editing `default.natstepfilter` (see [this link](http://mfctips.com/2014/04/01/how-to-not-step-into-functions-using-the-visual-studio-2013-debugger/)), but I don't think you can do it on a "skip all headers" kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the last version  Visual Studio. It has the [Just My Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/06/29/announcing-jmc-stepping-in-visual-studio/) option enabled by default. This makes the debugger skip "not that interesting" standard library code, including inline functions in system headers.